# Variable capture a button and pass it to a service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, service, controller

Hello community I am working a project with angular, but I get stuck with the following:

I want to capture a value that is inside of a button, the value comes from a controller, and click to pass this value to a service and that this service should go to another controller:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="capturaCtrl">
  <!--capturar valor en 'algunaVariable' con ng-click o ng-model se me ocurre para pasarla al service captura -->
   CODIGO A CAPTURAR: <button>{{capturame}}</button>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div ng-controller="recibeCtrl">
   CODIGO CAPTURADO: 
    {{codigo}}
  </div>
```

JS

```
    var app =  angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.factory('captura',  function(){
    var  codigo = algunaVariable; // <== variable que reciba del controllar capturaCtrl
    return{
      getCodes: function(){
        return codigo;
      }
    }
  });

  app.controller('capturaCtrl', ['$scope', 'captura', function($scope, captura){
    $scope.capturame = '1111';

  }]);


  app.controller('recibeCtrl', ['$scope', 'captura', function($scope, captura){
    $scope.codigo = captura.getCodes();

  }]);
```

Here I give you my code worked: https://jsfiddle.net/alx_lopz/wgfh3dLa/5/

Comment: Use AngularJS services to share data between controllers [AngularJS Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). I made an example that suits your case: [Example](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/gPBJVO?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a setter function to your factory.

```
  app.factory('captura',  function(){
    var  codigo = "initial value"; // <== variable que reciba del controllar capturaCtrl
    return{
      getCodes: function(){
        return codigo;
      },
      setCodes: function(value) {
        codigo = value;
        return value;
      }
    }
  });
```

Add `ng-click` to your button

```
CODIGO A CAPTURAR: <button ng-click="setCodigo(capturame)">
                       {{capturame}}
                   </button>
```

Convert the retrieval to a function

```
CODIGO CAPTURADO: {{ codigo() }}
```

Put the functions on the scope

```
  app.controller('capturaCtrl', ['$scope', 'captura', function($scope, captura){
    $scope.capturame = '1111';
    $scope.setCodigo = captura.setCodes;

  }]);

  app.controller('recibeCtrl', ['$scope', 'captura', function($scope, captura){
    $scope.codigo = captura.getCodes;

  }]);
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th1qu2dr/).